# Design Android App for Samsung Edge Panel with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, samsung-edge

The Samsung Note Edge has few applications just for the edge panel on the right, But I am trying to create a project from Android Studio, Anyone has any idea how to begin. I only see options for Wearables, Google glass, TV, Phones and Tablets.

I got the SDK http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile#look But I am not sure how it should be integrated to start an Application.

I know that questions asked w/o what is being tried is a bad thing, but I have looked all over the internet not much articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you unzip the Samsung Look SDK, you should find some .jar files in a folder called `libs`. Copy those to your app's `libs` directory (which Android Studio automatically creates) and they should be picked up by your gradle build. If not, check that you have this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // other dependencies here ...
}
```

Comment: Ok I added in the lib folder, Do you know a sample Hello World for the Edge Panel ?

Comment: Github link maybe ?? Or any Article will do

Comment: @joyBlanks No, i don't. I've never used this SDK. Samsung has instructions and documentation on the very website you linked to, that's where I would start.